# BrightScript - Can an Associative Array hold another Array as a Value?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm new to BrightScript and am trying to figure out how to work with their associative arrays. My questions is, can an associative array in BrightScript hold another array as a value?

I'm trying to parse an associative array that looks like this:

```
showList = {Romance: 
        [
            {
                Title: "The Notebook",
                releaseDate: "2000"
            }
        ], 

    Comedy:
        [
            {
                Title: "Caddyshack",
                releaseDate: "1976"
            }
        ]
     }
```

If I use a statement like this:

```
return showlist["Comedy"]
```

Will this only return an array containing my Comedy video meta-data?

It seems like this should work, but I've been having trouble implementing this. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
`showList["Comedy"]` or `showList.comedy` give you

```
[ { Title: "Caddyshack", releaseDate: "1976" } ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this right after I posted the question and it worked. The problem I was running into was really from the way I was storing the array inside the showlist variable

Comment: Because I placed a linebreak after "Romance: ", BrightScript wasn't recognizing the code as a valid associative array. I believe showlist was coming back as <UNINITIALIZED> when I tried to access it. I think the linebreaks were causing that problem.